# Taking a 'White' pixel count of each masked frame in a video file

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to develop a way to output the number of pixels that fall between the HSV mask limits of each frame of a given video on a Raspberry Pi camera.

The aim of this is to determine the 'Red' intensity of a red dimmer light and therefore split its intensity into different levels, and hence determine which intensity the light is switched to in each frame. How would I go about calculating said pixel count?

My progress so far is that I have a method and limits for masking a frame using OpenCV commands. I just need a way to count the remaining pixels of each frame.

Here is my current code, which I have slightly adapted from this great tutorial I found: *[Automatic Vision Object Tracking](https://www.hackster.io/mjrobot/automatic-vision-object-tracking-5575c4)*

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('hsvmeasure.jpg', 1)

img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([160,100,100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_range = np.array([180,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

while(1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if (k == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Original JPEG file of red light]

[image: Masked image]

Comment: Could you please provide some pictures illustrating the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please add a sample image and your code that masks the red colours. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Guys, apologies for the delayed response, Ive only just gained enough reputation to post images to this (Im new to stack overflow)

Comment: Do you want all the red pixels or only the ones inside the circle? See https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html using Numpy. Here is a recommendation. Always search Google for your query and include Python OpenCV Numpy. Also one can post images to any free hosting service and put the URLs in a comment or question

Answer (score 1):

You have already done most of the work, now you can just make a range of lower and upper intensity (non-overlapping) and count how many pixels are 255 in the mask.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 1)

img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_intensity_levels = [ [150,100,100], [161, 100,100], [171, 100, 100] ] # non overlapping
upper_intensity_levels = [ [160,255,255] , [170, 255, 255], [180, 255, 255] ] # make these list based on your intensity requirements 
mask_on_counts = []
for i in range(len(lower_intensity_levels)):
    lower_range = np.array(lower_intensity_levels[i], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_range = np.array(upper_intensity_levels[i], dtype=np.uint8)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

    mask_on_counts.append(np.sum(mask==255))

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.imshow(mask)
    plt.show()

for i in range(len(mask_on_counts)):
    print(f'level {i+1} number of pixels: {mask_on_counts[i]}')
```

[image]